# How do I look for the TD inside a TR that is below the TR that I click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, append

The purpose of this code is to make an ajax call if the `<td>` contained within the `<tr>` that is below the `<tr>` that was clicked, but only if the hidden `<tr>` is empty.  Eventually I plan to take that data and do something with it, but for right now, I just need to get this thing which emulates an accordion as a table working.  Due to this table being made on the same html file that I have other `.hidden` elements on, I had to create custom classes to hide these particular ones.  The class `detail-view` makes it visible, and the class `hidden-detail` contains `display:none`.  I know that postDetails works as far as finding the right data.  What i'm more worried about is finding out why FireFox's dev tools say `statusRow` and `detPane` are marked as `(unavailable)` throughout this code, whereas `statusRow.closest('tr').next('tr')` actually appears to contain the row `detPane`, as intended.  Is there something wrong with the jQuery or selectors?  What's going on here?

```
function makeOrderTable(response, username, sesstoken) {
    $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))).each(function() {
        var foNum = this['Factory Order#'];
        var pO = this['PO#'];
        var status = this['Status'];
        var shipDate = this['Ship Date'];
        $('.orders tbody').append(
            '<tr class="status-row">'+
                '<td>' + foNum + '</td><td>' + pO  + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + shipDate + '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr class="detail-row hidden-detail">'+
                '<td colspan="4"></td>'+
            '</tr>'
        );
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table').on('click', 'tr.status-row', function() {
            var statusRow = $(this);
            var detPane = $(statusRow[0]).closest('tr').next('tr');
            $('.detail-view').addClass('hidden-detail');
            $('.detail-view').removeClass('detail-view');
            detPane.addClass('detail-view');
            detPane.removeClass('hidden-detail');

            if (detPane.find('td').text == '')
            {
                var value = statusRow.find('td:first-child').text();
                postDetails(value, username, sesstoken, detPane.find('td'));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Side note: `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))` is saying to take the object, turn it into json, and then turn it back into an object.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: Also if the value you are giving `$()` is not a selector or (array of) dom elements, you should use the `$.each(array|object, function)` version rather than the `$(selector|element|array of elements, function).each()` version.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: `$(statusRow[0])` is a waste why are you taking a jQuery object, reading the DOM element, and than converting it back into the same jQuery object.

Comment: `detPane.find('td').text` is wrong, `text()` is a method, not a property

Comment: @Taplar idk, it just works that way.  It gets stuff, and if i move my ajax call inside the loop, instead of being on click, it all works beautifully.  But i need the on clicks in there.

Comment: It is working.  The things epascarello and I are pointing out are places where you are performing unnecessary work and we are trying to explain to you why that is.  Except for the text thing.  That is a logic error.

Comment: So it's throwing all the info into the first cell, and isn't using the whole td element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that as epascarello pointed out, `text` isn't a valid property.  Ergo, couldn't find anything.  But, I also needed to grab the details td separately--i.e. couldn't access things from other things and just daisy-chain selectors all over the place.  So, here's the end result.

```
function makeOrderTable(response, username, sesstoken) {
    $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))).each(function() {
        var foNum = this['Factory Order#'];
        var pO = this['PO#'];
        var status = this['Status'];
        var shipDate = this['Ship Date'];
        $('.orders tbody').append(
            '<tr class="status-row">'+
                '<td>' + foNum + '</td><td>' + pO  + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + shipDate + '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr class="detail-row hidden-detail">'+
                '<td colspan="4"></td>'+
            '</tr>'
        );
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table').on('click', 'tr.status-row', function() {
            var statusRow = $(this);
            var detRow = statusRow.closest('tr').next('tr');
            var details = this.nextElementSibling.querySelector('td');
            $('.detail-view').addClass('hidden-detail');
            $('.detail-view').removeClass('detail-view');
            detRow.addClass('detail-view');
            detRow.removeClass('hidden-detail');

            if (details.innerText == '')
            {
                var value = statusRow.find('td:first-child').text();
                postDetails(value, username, sesstoken, details);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, I think your selector for the "hidden" tr is incorrect.

You have the click event attached to the `tr`, so you shouldn't have to do `.closest('tr')`. Just `var detPane = $(statusRow[0]).next('tr');` should get you the next `tr` after the one that was clicked.

Comment: FYI: closest checks itself first